# How to remove text services?

Tags: automator, services

I know service workflows created from Automator can be removed from `~/Library/Services`, but I cannot see any services related to selected text there.

See my screenshots
[image]

I must have installed apps that added such services the LaTeX series in the screenshot, which shows up in the context menu when right-clicking text in apps like Notes.

How to remove these services then?

Answer (score 1):

OK, found it myself. Under `System Preferences` > `Keyboard` > `Shortcuts` > `Services`, I can uncheck those 3rd-party services.